# OData not returning @odata.context and @odata.nextLink- Just returns result in values

Tags: odata, asp.net-core-3.1

We are developing OData API using (.Net Core 3.1/.Net 5.0 and OData Version 8.0.11), where we have registered DataModle with IEDM, but in the response of the API we are not getting the IEDM Contract, instead we are getting only the array of values, like shown below. Not sure if we are missing something, your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
[
    {
        "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "code": "Code1"
    },
    {
        "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001",
        "code": "Code2"
    }
]
```

But we should be getting the response in the below IEDM contract, which we are not getting!

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://localhost:44338/$metadata#Event",
    "value": [
    {
    "@odata.type": "#ODataPOC.Event",
    "@odata.id": "https://localhost:44338/Event(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000)",
    "@odata.editLink": "Event(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000)",
    "Id@odata.type": "#Guid",
    "Id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
    },
    {
    "@odata.type": "#ODataPOC.Event",
    "@odata.id": "https://localhost:44338/Event(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000)",
    "@odata.editLink": "Event(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001)",
    "Id@odata.type": "#Guid",
    "Id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001"
    }
    ],
"@odata.nextLink": "https://localhost:44338/event?$skip=2"
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and the reason was that the OData Endpoint Mapping was not working. You can verify this by adding

`app.UseODataRouteDebug();`

in the StartUp.

This allows you to see the mapped endpoints with https://localhost/$odata, your controllers should be listed under "OData Endpoint Mappings".

If this is not the case the controller is not mapped as OData Endpoint.

In my case I could resolve it by ensuring the controller name is same as the entity name used in the StartUp:

```
 builder.EntitySet<Entity>("EntityName");
```

The controller should be names like this:

```
public class EntityNameController:ODataController
```